# Implementing Queue With Two Stacks - Dequeuing Test Issue?

Tags: c++, stack, queue

I'm trying to implement a queue with two stacks for purposes of understanding both data structures a little better. I have the below, with the main function serving as a test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class _Stack : public stack<T> {
   public:
T pop(){
    T tmp=stack::top();
    stack::pop();
    return tmp;
}
};

 template <class T>

 class QueueS {

 public:
QueueS(){}

bool isEmpty() const{ 

return pool.empty();

}


void enqueue(const T& el){

    while( !output.empty()) {
        input.push(output.pop());
    }

    input.push(el);

}

T dequeue(){

    while(!input.empty()){
         output.push(input.pop());
     }

     return output.pop();

}


T firstElement(){

    if(output.empty()) {

               return NULL;

    }

     return output.top();

}

 private:
_Stack<T> pool;
_Stack<T> input;
_Stack<T> output;

 };

 int main(){

QueueS<int> n_QueueS;

//fill the queue of integers 0-9
for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
    n_QueueS.enqueue(i);    

// add another number to the queue
n_QueueS.enqueue(50);

//retrieve the first element without removing it
cout<<"front of the queue: "<<n_QueueS.firstElement()<<endl;

// removing the first 5 elements from the queue
cout<<"deleting first five elements of the queue: ";
for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
    cout<<n_QueueS.dequeue()<<" ";

 //removing the remainder of the queue and displaying the result
//should see 5 6 7 8 9 50 - see nothing!
cout<<endl<<"deleting remainder of the queue: ";
while(!n_QueueS.isEmpty())
    cout<<n_QueueS.dequeue()<<" ";

if(n_QueueS.isEmpty())
    cout<<endl<<"Queue is now empty";
else 
    cout<<endl<<"Error in emptying the queue";

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

It works pretty well thusfar. However, when I run my test, deleting the first five elements works fine, and they display fine. It displays the line "deleting first five elements of the queue:" followed by 0 1 2 3 4, as expected.

However, deleting the second half doesn't display the values after the text "deleting remainder of the queue" like the previous test case did. I'm assuming the problem is minor, but I can't locate it through debugging. Maybe I've overlooked something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Stack`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implantation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your empty check should be something like this:

```
bool isEmpty() const{
   return input.empty() && output.empty();
}
```

in enqueue, just push to the input stack:

```
void enqueue(const T& el){
   input.push(el);    
}
```

in enqueue and dequeue, move input to output if output is empty:

```
T dequeue(){
    if (output.empty())
       while(!input.empty()){
         output.push(input.pop());
       }
    // throw exception of output.empty() ??
    return output.pop();
}

T firstElement(){
   if (output.empty())
     while(!input.empty()){
        output.push(input.pop());
     }
   if(output.empty()) {
      return T(0);   // throw exception?
   }
   return output.top();
}
```

Comment: Hang on, I'm not too sure about that. I want the final product to act like a queue. So, from LIFO structure to FIFO. If I take your advice and just push to a single stack, my first element will forever be on the bottom! Also, it may not have been clear, but I want firstElement to return the topmost value without removing it, so I think what I have is fine.

Comment: Hmmm, but making your change to isEmpty seems to have corrected my issue, somehow. Unless it decided to fix itself... Regardless, thanks for that point!

Comment: @Rome_Leader, if you only do the transfer to the output stack when it is empty, the items you push to the input will be flipped and they will not be at the bottom forever. If you hand iterate the algorithm you will see.